# How to align centers of two div

Tags: html, css

I want to show a circle in webpage at some X and Y and then show title text just above the circle.

What I want is - Center of the text should match with center of circle vertically(Y).

Even when the length of text is increased at run-time, the text should still be centered.

Circle dia and text length are variable.

I tried to use `text-align center`, but could not achieve.

**html -**

```
<div id="par">
    <div id="txt">Some Text</div>
    <div id="circ"></div>
</div>
```

**css -**

```
#par{
    text-align: center;
}

#txt{
    background-color: red;
}

#circ {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far. Show us your code.

Comment: hi, please share your current code so we can better understand what you are trying to achive

Comment: it's possible with flex-box , but share a picture to get more info

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;` for the wrapper element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you:

```css
#par{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
}

#txt{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

#circ {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="par">
    <div id="txt">Some Text</div>
    <div id="circ"></div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div id="par">
    <div id="txt">Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</div>
    <div id="circ"></div>
</div>
```